# Error with UniqueEntity validator for integer field if string is inputed

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-validator

Could you please tell how to avoid the error with validator for integer type if string value is inputed in the from?

The error message looks like this (and happens during checking for uniqueness):

```
SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "1050177d"
```

I have an Entity with integer field campaignId that should be unique for all entities.
For entity I added this constraint.

```
@UniqueEntity("campaignId")
```

The field looks like this one:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Type("integer")
 * @Assert\Positive
 * @ORM\Column(type="bigint", unique=true)
 * @var int
 */
private $campaignId;
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably want validation groups to check the property/field assertions first (especially, since it doesn't involve database access, that may fail and trash the entity manager), see: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html and https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/validation_groups.html

As far as I can tell, if you provide multiple validation groups, it won't check the latter, if the former already has a violation.